# Turing decidable languages

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

On an old worksheet I came across the question

> If L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> are two Turing decidable languages, then show that <sub>1</sub>∪<sub>2</sub> and <sub>1</sub><sub>2</sub> are Turing decidable languages (high-level description with stages is enough).

How do I go about answering this without being given a language to work from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are decidable. Hence, they have algorithms $A_1$ and $A_2$ (respectively) that decide them.

Try to create a new turing machine (algorithm) using the two algorithms $A_1$ and $A_2$.

For example, for the union $L_1\cup L_2$, you can create the following algorithm:

- run $A_1$ on the input. If it accepted, then also accept.
- else, run $A_2$ on the input, and return what $A_2$ returned.

Comment: I was able to understand this and I was able to do the same if it was intersection, but how does this work for concatenation? Thanks by the way!

Comment: Try to enumerate on all prefixes

Comment: For each enumeration check if each of the two parts are in $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively